# Itext in Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, pdf-generation, itext

I am trying to generate a pdf at the click of a button in eclipse in an android application.I have followed [vogella's tutorial](http://www.vogella.de/articles/Eclipse/article.html#classpath) as a java project.

This is the code for my java project which works beautifully.

```
package de.vogella.eclipse.ide.first;


import java.io.*;
import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
import com.itextpdf.text.Paragraph;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;

public class MyFirstClass {

    public static void main(String arg[])throws Exception{
          Document document=new Document();
          PdfWriter.getInstance(document,new FileOutputStream("StudentPDF.pdf"));
          document.open();  
          document.add(new Paragraph("Test StudentPdf"));
          document.close(); 
          }
    }
```

However when I duplicate this code over to my android app's new java class, I get "Error occurred during initialization of VM
java.lang.StackOverflowError" when i try to run the class as a java application and it crashes the program when I run it through the application.

This error completely points to how i have the iText library installed. I've checked, double checked and triple checked the source attachement, javadoc and the native library location. They all seem to be installed just like the java project.

This is my android javaclass file

```
import java.io.*;
import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
import com.itextpdf.text.Paragraph;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;

public class iText {

public static void Print(String arg[])throws Exception{
      Document document=new Document();
      PdfWriter.getInstance(document,new FileOutputStream("StudentPDF.pdf"));
      document.open();  
      document.add(new Paragraph("Test StudentPdf"));
      document.close(); 
      }
}
```

My "print" button's onClick listener is set to Print.

So in theory once it is clicked, this java class should activate and generate a pdf. Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing to try out is adding permissions to manifest file. If all of your code works all right with android permissions would help.

Comment: What kind of permissions would you suggest?

Comment: try adding WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and output your pdf file to external storage.